# PHP subdirectories without folders

Tags: php, html, subdirectory

I'm wondering if it is possible convert something like this
example:

```
www.news.com/news.php
www.news.com/post.php?id=5
```

to this:

```
www.news.com/news
www.news.com/news/post.php?id=6
```

without creating folders for each file and how can i do that.

thanks

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: 100% possible. If you're using Apache, just use mod_rewrite.

Answer (score -1):

You sure can.  It's not a function of PHP though, you'd be better off doing this at a server level.

If you're using Apache, take a look at "apache rewrites".  You'd be creating an "htaccess" file to do so.

Start here and create a new question if you run in to any specific problems: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html